# "nativeSdkIntegration failed to be installed" error with sentry_flutter on android

Tags: android, flutter, sentry

I installed sentry_flutter recently and it work fine on IOS (errors are sent and stuff), but when I try on Android it impossible to make it work ! sentry throw an error telling me that "nativeSdkIntegration failed to be installed" and of course no error is received by sentry

There is the full error :

```
[sentry] [fatal] nativeSdkIntegration failed to be installed
         MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method initNativeSdk on channel sentry_flutter)
         #0      MethodChannel._invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:156:7)
         <asynchronous suspension>
         #1      NativeSdkIntegration.call (package:sentry_flutter/src/default_integrations.dart:234:7)
         <asynchronous suspension>
         #2      Sentry._callIntegrations (package:sentry/src/sentry.dart:131:7)
         <asynchronous suspension>
         #3      Sentry._init.<anonymous closure> (package:sentry/src/sentry.dart:111:9)
         <asynchronous suspension>
         #4      RunZonedGuardedIntegration.call.<anonymous closure> (package:sentry/src/default_integrations.dart:27:9)
         <asynchronous suspension>
[sentry] [error] Failed to load release and dist
         MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method getAll on channel dev.fluttercommunity.plus/package_info)
         #0      MethodChannel._invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:156:7)
         <asynchronous suspension>
         #1      MethodChannel.invokeMapMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:358:43)
         <asynchronous suspension>
         #2      MethodChannelPackageInfo.getAll (package:package_info_plus_platform_interface/method_channel_package_info.dart:13:17)
         <asynchronous suspension>
         #3      PackageInfo.fromPlatform (package:package_info_plus/package_info_plus.dart:67:26)
         <asynchronous suspension>
         #4      _loadPackageInfo (package:sentry_flutter/src/sentry_flutter.dart:133:10)
         <asynchronous suspension>
         #5      LoadReleaseIntegration.call (package:sentry_flutter/src/default_integrations.dart:426:29)
         <asynchronous suspension>
         #6      Sentry._callIntegrations (package:sentry/src/sentry.dart:131:7)
         <asynchronous suspension>
         #7      Sentry._init.<anonymous closure> (package:sentry/src/sentry.dart:111:9)
         <asynchronous suspension>
         #8      RunZonedGuardedIntegration.call.<anonymous closure> (package:sentry/src/default_integrations.dart:27:9)
         <asynchronous suspension>
I/flutter (18161): unhandled element filter; Picture key: StringPicture(String#bcac4, colorFilter: null)
I/flutter (18161): 00000000000000000000000000000000
[sentry] [error] Failed to save envelope
         MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method captureEnvelope on channel sentry_flutter)
         #0      MethodChannel._invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:156:7)
         <asynchronous suspension>
         #1      FileSystemTransport.send (package:sentry_flutter/src/file_system_transport.dart:19:7)
         <asynchronous suspension>
         #2      SentryClient.captureEvent (package:sentry/src/sentry_client.dart:117:16)
         <asynchronous suspension>
         #3      Hub.captureException (package:sentry/src/hub.dart:117:20)
         <asynchronous suspension>
```

And there is my flutter doctor :

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.2.3, on macOS 11.3 20E232 darwin-x64, locale fr-FR)
    • Flutter version 2.2.3 at /Users/artha77/fvm/versions/2.2.3
    • Framework revision f4abaa0735 (10 weeks ago), 2021-07-01 12:46:11 -0700
    • Engine revision 241c87ad80
    • Dart version 2.13.4

[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.2)
    • Android SDK at /Users/artha77/Library/Android/sdk
    • Platform android-30, build-tools 29.0.2
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.10+0-b96-7281165)
    ✗ Android license status unknown.
      Run `flutter doctor --android-licenses` to accept the SDK licenses.
      See https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/macos#android-setup for more details.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Xcode 12.4, Build version 12D4e
    • CocoaPods version 1.11.0

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome

[✓] Android Studio (version 2020.3)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.10+0-b96-7281165)

[✓] IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate Edition (version 2021.2.1)
    • IntelliJ at /Users/artha77/Applications/JetBrains Toolbox/IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate.app
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart

[✓] Connected device (3 available)
    • Android SDK built for x86 (mobile) • emulator-5554                        • android-x86    • Android 9 (API 28) (emulator)
    • iPhone XS (mobile)                 • 91E82161-65F5-486C-891C-A8FFE0B8E714 • ios            • com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-12-0 (simulator)
    • Chrome (web)                       • chrome                               • web-javascript • Google Chrome 95.0.4628.3 dev

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.
Process finished with exit code 0
```

I don't really understand what's wrong ?

Comment: Have you tried the `flutter clean && flutter pub get` commands in your terminal ?

Comment: @esentis yes same error :/